# DialogFragment disappears on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

This fairly simple dialog dismisses itself after screen rotation despite I setRetainInstance to true. Any ideas whats wrong?

```
public class StreetDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static StreetDialog newInstance(String[] values) {
        StreetDialog f = new StreetDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArray("values", values);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final String[] values = getArguments().getStringArray("values");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //build my dialog
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
            getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);

        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly is the normal behaviour. I usually provide a tag to the show method, and when the Activity's onCreate is called again, I look for the tag. If the fragment != null I create a new instance and show it again

Comment: @blackbelt but fragment != null assumes that there already is a fragment with such tag. If you add the same fragment again will the old fragment still be in the view hierarchy?

Comment: yes it does. I remove it, before showing the new one, because a you need the fragment manager to show the dialog fragment and I don't know if it is bounded to the activity's instance,

Comment: try by adding android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" in manifest.xml

Comment: @blackbelt can you please post your comment as an answer and show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly is the normal behaviour. I usually provide a tag to the show method, and when the Activity's onCreate is called again, I look for the tag. If the fragment != null I remove it, before creating and showing the new one. In code, what I usually do is:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
if (fragment != null) {
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
}
new CustomDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_TAG );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that I believe the best way to solve and using an approach below:

Create a static method to initialize a Dialog, remembering that this is a good practice since we always have the default constructor and the Bundle stores the state of the Fragment. 
In onCreateDialog method, initialize the AlertDialog with the data passed in the "constructor method". 
In your Activity you can implement an interface (because we can not keep the reference of it, since it may have been destroyed when rotating the device). To open the dialog, 
checking that it has been added to FragmentManager otherwise exhibit.

see more here (Link in portuguese - br): http://nglauber.blogspot.com.br/2013_10_01_archive.html

```
public class SimpleDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {  

  private static final    String EXTRA_ID      = "id";  
  private static final   String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";  
  private static final   String EXTRA_TITLE   = "title";  
  private static final   String EXTRA_BUTTONS = "buttons";  
  private static final   String DIALOG_TAG    = "SimpleDialog";  

  private int dialogId;  

  public static SimpleDialog newDialog(int id,   
    String title, String message, int[] buttonTexts){  
    // Using the Bundle to save state  
    Bundle bundle  = new Bundle();  
    bundle.putInt(EXTRA_ID, id);  
    bundle.putString(EXTRA_TITLE, title);   
    bundle.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);  
    bundle.putIntArray(EXTRA_BUTTONS, buttonTexts);  

    SimpleDialog dialog = new SimpleDialog();  
    dialog.setArguments(bundle);  
    return dialog;   
  }  

  @Override  
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    String title = getArguments() .getString(EXTRA_TITLE);  
    String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);  
    int[] buttons = getArguments().getIntArray(EXTRA_BUTTONS);  

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());  
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);  
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);  

    switch (buttons.length) {  
      case 3:  
        alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton(buttons[2], this);  

      case 2:  
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(buttons[1], this);  

      case 1:  
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(buttons[0], this);  
    }      
    return alertDialogBuilder.create();  
  }  

  @Override  
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
    // Your Activity must to implements this interface  
    ((FragmentDialogInterface)getActivity()).onClick(dialogId, which);  
  }  

  public void openDialog( FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {  

    if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag( DIALOG_TAG) == null){  
        show(supportFragmentManager, DIALOG_TAG);  
    }    
  }  
  // Interface that was invoked by clicking the button  
  public interface FragmentDialogInterface {  
    void onClick(int id, int which);  
  }
```

To open the dialog in your activity

```
public void openSimpleDialog(View v) {  
  SimpleDialog dialog = SimpleDialog.newDialog(  
    0,              // Id from dialog  
    "Alert",       // title
    "Message",     // menssage  
    new int[]{      // texts from buttons
      android.R.string.ok,   
      android.R.string.cancel });  
    dialog.openDialog(getSupportFragmentManager());  
  }  

  @Override  
  public void onClick(int id, int which) {  
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,   
      "Button clicked"+ which, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)  
        .show();  
  }
```